# Deleting row and changing category- SQL

Tags: sql

I have a problem with changing categories of column 'size_category'.

```
SELECT
    CAST(u.balance_date AS date) AS snapshot_date,
    p.process_name,
    f.function_name,
    u.unit_type,
    u.job_action,
    u.size_category,
    SUM(u.unit_count) AS units
FROM
    units u
    INNER JOIN processes p ON u.process_id = p.process_id
    INNER JOIN functions f ON u.function_id = f.function_id

GROUP BY
   1,2,3,4,5,6
```

| snapshot_date | process_name | function_name | unit_type | job_action | size_category | units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-10 | process_1 | function_1 | type_1 | job_action_1 | Total | 23442 |
| 2022-12-10 | process_1 | function_1 | type_2 | job_action_1 | Total | 21313 |
| 2022-12-10 | process_1 | function_1 | type_2 | job_action_1 | Undefined | 21313 |
| 2022-12-10 | process_1 | function_1 | type_1 | job_action_1 | Medium | 17678 |
| 2022-12-10 | process_1 | function_1 | type_1 | job_action_1 | Small | 5171 |
| 2022-12-10 | process_1 | function_1 | type_1 | job_action_1 | Large | 578 |
| 2022-12-10 | process_1 | function_1 | type_1 | job_action_1 | Undefined | 15 |

I need to delete a row or enter null if 'Units' for the 'Total' and 'Undefined' size categories are the same. In addition, if the size category is 'Undefined' but 'Units' is different categorise these unities as Small in size category.

Expected output as below.

| snapshot_date | process_name | function_name | unit_type | job_action | size_category | units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/10/2022 | process_1 | function_1 | type_1 | job_action_1 | Total | 23442 |
| 12/10/2022 | process_1 | function_1 | type_2 | job_action_1 | Total | 21313 |
| 12/10/2022 | process_1 | function_1 | type_1 | job_action_1 | Medium | 17678 |
| 12/10/2022 | process_1 | function_1 | type_1 | job_action_1 | Small | 5171 |
| 12/10/2022 | process_1 | function_1 | type_1 | job_action_1 | Large | 578 |
| 12/10/2022 | process_1 | function_1 | type_1 | job_action_1 | Small | 15 |

Comment: could you please provide the expected output?

Comment: Hi, expected output above.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few approaches to this scenario, here you have a solution leveraging self-joins.

Let's first recap the challenges here:

1. Remove records with "undefined" category, only when the rest of the fields are the same
2. Retain records with "undefined" category, those with unique fields.
3. Replace "undefined" by "small" for those unique "undefined" records found in challenge 2.

The solution >

**Source data**: I have created a source_data CTE with the input data. Your input data is different since you are grouping and joining fields and tables but it is not relevant to the solution.

In your real use case, you can replace this CTE with your actual query.

**Base dataset**: This CTE contains the base data with all records, to perform aggregations so that all calculations are ok.

**SQL query**: Here we are joining the base dataset but on the left side we have all not "undefined" category records and on the right side all "undefined" category records.

The JOIN must consider all fields that are common.

The FULL OUTER JOIN will take unique values from each side, therefore the second and third rows will be joined on a single record. This is how the query solves your first challenge.

The COALESCE functions will first inspect the fields coming from the not undefined side, if they have any value the result will show it.

If they don't have any value, then we have a unique undefined record that we must preserve, so we take the undefined value.

This is how we solve your second challenge.

Finally, since you want to replace the "undefined" category, the coalesce function takes a fixed value ('small') rather than the actual value ('undefined')

This is how we solve your third challenge.

Here you have a working query:

```
-- source input data   
WITH source_data AS
      (SELECT '2022-12-10' AS snapshot_date,
              'process_1' AS process_name,
              'function_1' AS function_name,
              'type_1' AS unit_type,
              'job_action_1' AS job_action,
              'Total' AS size_category,
              23442 AS units
       UNION ALL SELECT '2022-12-10',
                        'process_1',
                        'function_1',
                        'type_2',
                        'job_action_1',
                        'Total',
                        21313
       UNION ALL SELECT '2022-12-10',
                        'process_1',
                        'function_1',
                        'type_2',
                        'job_action_1',
                        'Undefined',
                        21313
       UNION ALL SELECT '2022-12-10',
                        'process_1',
                        'function_1',
                        'type_1',
                        'job_action_1',
                        'Medium',
                        17678
       UNION ALL SELECT '2022-12-10',
                        'process_1',
                        'function_1',
                        'type_1',
                        'job_action_1',
                        'Small',
                        5171
       UNION ALL SELECT '2022-12-10',
                        'process_1',
                        'function_1',
                        'type_1',
                        'job_action_1',
                        'Large',
                        578
       UNION ALL SELECT '2022-12-10',
                        'process_1',
                        'function_1',
                        'type_1',
                        'job_action_1',
                        'Undefined',
                        15),
         
-- base table including aggregations
base_table AS
      (SELECT CAST(snapshot_date AS date) AS snapshot_date,
              process_name,
              function_name,
              unit_type,
              job_action,
              size_category,
              SUM(units) AS units
       FROM source_data
       GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6)

-- SQL query for expected results
    SELECT COALESCE(not_undefined.snapshot_date, undefined.snapshot_date) AS snapshot_date,
           COALESCE(not_undefined.process_name, undefined.process_name) AS process_name,
           COALESCE(not_undefined.function_name, undefined.function_name) AS function_name,
           COALESCE(not_undefined.unit_type, undefined.unit_type) AS unit_type,
           COALESCE(not_undefined.job_action, undefined.job_action) AS job_action,
           COALESCE(not_undefined.size_category, 'Small') AS size_category,
           COALESCE(not_undefined.units, undefined.units) AS units
    FROM
      (SELECT *
       FROM base_table
       WHERE size_category <> 'Undefined') not_undefined
    FULL OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT *
       FROM base_table
       WHERE size_category = 'Undefined') undefined ON not_undefined.function_na

me= undefined.function_name
AND not_undefined.unit_type = undefined.unit_type
AND not_undefined.job_action = undefined.job_action
AND not_undefined.units = undefined.units
```

The output is:

| snapshot_date | process_name | function_name | unit_type | job_action | size_category | units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-10 | process_1 | function_1 | type_1 | job_action_1 | Total | 23442 |
| 2022-12-10 | process_1 | function_1 | type_2 | job_action_1 | Total | 21313 |
| 2022-12-10 | process_1 | function_1 | type_1 | job_action_1 | Medium | 17678 |
| 2022-12-10 | process_1 | function_1 | type_1 | job_action_1 | Small | 5171 |
| 2022-12-10 | process_1 | function_1 | type_1 | job_action_1 | Large | 578 |
| 2022-12-10 | process_1 | function_1 | type_1 | job_action_1 | Small | 15 |